# Haskell make recipe fails for Paradox theorem prover using GHC

Tags: linux, haskell, makefile, ghc, theorem-proving

I am trying to install the paradox theorem prover sourced from [here](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~koen/code/).

When I run the makefile this is the command that runs:
`ghc -optl -static -lstdc++ -I../instantiate -I../minisat/current-base ../minisat/current-base/Solver.or ../minisat/current-base/Prop.or ../instantiate/MiniSatWrapper.or ../instantiate/MiniSatInstantiateClause.or -fglasgow-exts -O2 -static -threaded -main-is Paradox.Main.main --make Paradox.Main -o paradox`

And it results in several errors like so:

```
Flags.hs:52:8:
    Could not find module ‘Char’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

for a variety of modules including but not limited to `Char`, `CPUTime`, `IO`.

The final error message is

```
Makefile:38: recipe for target 'paradox.exe' failed
make: *** [paradox.exe] Error 1
```

I don't know Haskell, nor am I very experienced with GNU `make`, but I am trying to install this package for a project and it is obscure enough to not be packaged for my OS (I'm running Arch Linux). As far as I know it is not packaged for any OS, so it is necessary to install from source.

As far as I can tell the problem starts with the following error message:

`on the commandline: Warning:
    -fglasgow-exts is deprecated: Use individual extensions instead`

I am using the version of the GHC provided in the Arch Linux package repository: [package link](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/ghc/)

Comment: Please **include** the error message inside the question. Questions should be *self contained*. Links should only add references or further information, but shouldn't be relied upon to provide the meaning/essential information of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like paradox was written for a rather old version of GHC. You can fix all these "Could not find module" errors by using GHC version 7.8 or older and setting

```
GHC     = ghc -hide-package base -package haskell98
```

in the Makefile, though you will likely encounter more errors after that.

The warning about `-fglasgow-exts` is mostly harmless, you can ignore it.

Comment: That's natural. Most distributions still ship only the haskell platform 2013 which uses ghc 7.6.3.

Comment: FWIW they [gave up](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9590) supporting `haskell98` in GHC 7.10, as a consequence of the AMP reform. The problem is that the `Monad` class, which is deeply embedded in the language (e.g. with `do` notation) is no longer backwards-compatible (it now has `Applicative` as superclass), so it's impossible to mix code using monads defined in the old and new style.